# Scala tail recursion optimization inside a match

Tags: scala, recursion, stack-overflow, tail-recursion

I am teaching myself Scala by trying to implement the operations on `List[T]`. I just implemented `dropWhile` and it made me wonder about how tail recursion optimization works when the recursive call appears in different cases.

```
def dropWhile[T](list: List[T])(predicate: T => Boolean): List[T] = list match {
  case head :: tail if predicate(head) => dropWhile(tail)(predicate)
  case _ => list
}
```

Does it matter that the recursive call appears in the first case?

Comment: No. It doesn't matter.

Comment: You can confirm this for yourself by putting `@scala.annotation.tailrec` in front of the definition—it's not necessary (i.e. the compiler may apply the optimization anyway), but if it compiles with the annotation, you know your code is written in such a way that the optimization can be applied.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As some one said in the comments, you can apply the `@tailrec` annotations to your function and it will give a compiler error if the recursion can not be optimized to a loop.

Where the recursive call is does not matter. The important part is that there is no need for a stack frame to stay allocated *waiting* for the return from the recursive calls.